# Grails calendar plugin returns null date if user doesn't pick a date

Tags: grails, calendar

I was using the grails calendar plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/calendar) and if I don't click on the calendar icon and click on a date, my controller gets a null for the date. If I click on a date, it works fine.

Question - is this normal? is this how it is supposed to work?

I expected the defaultDate I set in the gsp to be returned. I'm new to grails and groovy so I could be doing something wrong.

Since this plugin is so old, maybe everyone uses something else?

I'm using netbeans 8.5, java 7, calendar 1.2.1, on windows7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you linked to say that this is normal and null is the default value for the date. If you want to change the default date you need to set the *defaultValue* attribute e.g.

```
<calendar:datePicker name="date" dateFormat="%d/%m/%Y" defaultValue="${new Date()}"/>
```

Comment: I guess I hadn't read that line very carefully. Thanks for pointing it out.  

I am using the defaultDate so I'll keep digging and try to get this working.  

`<calendar:datePicker name="insertDate" required="false" minYear="2000" showTime="true" dateFormat="%d/%m/%Y : %H:%M" value="${new Date()}" defaultValue="${new Date()}"/>`